# Free() in C changing supposedly stored information

Tags: c, malloc, free

I'm trying to implement a simple database table in C using HashTable with 1009 buckets that contained a TupleList (Linked List) of Tuples.

Everything seems to be working except when I free the memory of the tuples I used. The table print then prints out unicode boxes and other random jargons, but peculiarly, only for one or so tuple entries.

---

A **Tuple**, **TupleList**, **Hash Table** is defined by:

```
struct Tuple {
  char *Course;
  int StudentId;
  char *Grade;
  TupleList next;
};

typedef struct Tuple Tuple;
typedef struct Tuple *TupleList;
typedef TupleList HashTable[1009];
```

A **Tuple** is allocated by:

```
Tuple *createCSGTuple(char *course, int id, char *grade){
  Tuple *tuple = (Tuple*)malloc(sizeof(Tuple));
  tuple->StudentId = id;
  tuple->Course = course;
  tuple->Grade = grade;

  return tuple;
}
```

**Insert** Method:

```
void insert(Tuple *tuple, int key){
  if(CSGTable[key] != NULL){//if there is already tuple(s) in the bucket
    tuple->next = CSGTable[key];//insert first 
    CSGTable[key] = tuple;
  }else{
    CSGTable[key] = tuple;
  }
}
```

**Print** Method:

```
void printCSGTable(){

  int key = 0;
  printf("\nCourse    StudentId    Grade\n");

  while(key < 1009){ //loops through every bucket

    if(CSGTable[key] != NULL){
      //temp Tuple for printing
      Tuple *temp = CSGTable[key];

      while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%-10s%-13d%-5s\n", temp->Course, temp->StudentId, temp >Grade);
        temp = temp->next;
      }    
    }
    key++;
  }
}
```

The **Test** Code (where CSGKey is a hash function that returns a key with Course and StudentId as the parameters):

```
Tuple *CSGtuple1 = createCSGTuple("CS121", 12345, "A");
Tuple *CSGtuple2 = createCSGTuple("CS121", 67890, "B");
Tuple *CSGtuple3 = createCSGTuple("EE100", 12345, "C");
Tuple *CSGtuple4 = createCSGTuple("EE100", 22222, "B+");

insert(CSGtuple1, "CSG", CSGKey(CSGtuple1->Course, CSGtuple1->StudentId));
insert(CSGtuple2, "CSG", CSGKey(CSGtuple2->Course, CSGtuple2->StudentId));
insert(CSGtuple3, "CSG", CSGKey(CSGtuple3->Course, CSGtuple3->StudentId));
insert(CSGtuple4, "CSG", CSGKey(CSGtuple4->Course, CSGtuple4->StudentId));

printCSGTable(); //BEFORE FREEING

free(CSGtuple1);
free(CSGtuple2);
free(CSGtuple3);
free(CSGtuple4);

printCSGTable();//AFTER FREEING
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Course    StudentId    Grade
CS121     67890        B
EE100     22222        B+
EE100     12345        C
CS121     12345        A

Course    StudentId    Grade
CS121     67890        B
EE100     22222        B+
EE100     12345        C
@}~       8266304      A
```

If I switch around the free like so:

```
free(CSGtuple2);
free(CSGtuple3);
free(CSGtuple4);
free(CSGtuple1);
```

The **OUTPUT** becomes:

```
Course    StudentId    Grade
CS121     67890        B
EE100     22222        B+
EE100     12345        C
CS121     12345        A

Course    StudentId    Grade
@}▒       13509184     B
EE100     22222        B+
EE100     12345        C
@}▒       13509184     A
```

---

It is to my understanding all the information has already been transferred to the Hash Table and thus there is no more need for the Tuples.

I'm not sure where this error is occurring in that it seems to occur sporadically and not for every tuple, or the Grade attribute. Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Feel free to edit if anything is unclear (Especially the title since I have no idea how to word this error!).

Comment: So, long story short, you are printing from pointers that you freed earlier? That is undefined behavior - you freed the memory, so the program is not allowed to access that memory again and it can contain *anything*.

Comment: Ah I see where your conceptual idea goes wrong: `tuple->next = CSGTable[key];` transfers the *pointer* but not its data. It is a "shallow" copy, rather than a "deep" one. Either make a deep copy (and make the table full structs rather than pointers), or, just don't think "I don't need this memory anymore" and only free the pointers when you're done.

Comment: `createCSGTuple()` doesn't set the value of `next` to `NULL`, and neither does `insert()`. As a result, you are liable to go marching off into the weeds when you call `printCSGTable()`.

Comment: You are not really creating a hash table, you allocated memory for 4 tuples and copying their address in your table, when you free the tuples, the table contains invalid address.  The reason you had still valid values after free is due to unspecified behaviour. Use a table of struct and deep copy functions like memset to create your hash table.

Comment: Thanks for the answers; @Rad Lexus is there any way to reduce memory so that I don't have to use free()?